# how to distribute osx program that uses dylibs?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, dylib

I wrote a small program (osx, c++) for image joining using opencv2 but I ran into a problem trying to send it to my friend who i wrote it for. The problem is that I only found two ways to build opencv2 and I could only build it into .dylib and .a files. I didn't know how to properly compile with the .a files and when i compile with .dylib files I couldn't make the program find them on another computer. How do I distribute a program that uses .dylib files for osx. I found a few answers to similar questions that mentioned changing the Dynamic Library Install Name in xcode and using the install_name_tool, but neither one of those helped or maybe I just used them wrong. I also tried finding a way to build opencv2 into a .framework for osx (not ios), but had no luck in my searches. I don't know where else to turn at this point.

Comment: The simplest way would be to compile with the .a. You should describe what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: I probably didn't know how to include the .a files into the project since my code couldn't find any part of opencv2 with .a files.

Comment: Are we talking about a linker error (where it says "undefined symbols") or compiler error (where it says "undeclared identifier" or something like that)?

Comment: I believe the "normal" way is to include them in the application bundle.

Comment: @zneak I tried again, and now i'm completely lost. Building with static libraries (.a) throws a runtime error "dyld: Library not loaded: libopencv_calib3d.2.4.dylib" "Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.2.4.dylib". I don't have any dylibs for building in the project (neither in Link Binary with Libraries, nor in anywhere else) also - the file "/usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.2.4.dylib" is there (like it exists in that place).

Comment: my bad. I deleted that .dylib file to check wether the program is still searching for it. I'm rebuilding the dylibs right now. But anyway - shouldn't the static library (.a) work without .dylib ? It has "static" in its name

Comment: @zneak ok so i rebuilt the dylibs, readded the missing ones to /usr/local/lib and now it works and runs. But how do i distribute the program? Or am i forced to distribute it with the dylibs? Because i thought that static libraries are "put into" the code at compile time so the program doesn't have external dependencies on user side.

Comment: A static library can have dependencies on dynamic libraries, which is what you seem to have here.